# Play TankiOnline on the desktop

Tags: flash, tanki-online

There is a game called TankiOnline.  The website is tankionline.com.  This game is played using Adobe Flash.

My question is, how can I play this game on the desktop, instead of going through a web browser?

I have already found [Adobe Flash 16 beta for Desktop](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer.html), but cannot see how to run the game.

Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: Just to clarify, I don't want to play offline - the game requires an Internet connection - I just want to use my own  files and connect to their servers.

Comment: Take a look at Oak's answer; it applies to any Flash game, not the specific one mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but no luck.  I don't wish to be offline - the very name of the game is Tanki Online - but I do wish to play it on the desktop instead of from a web browser, if possible.  Thanks though!

Comment: Playing on the desktop *is* offline play; there is literally zero difference, unless the game itself requires an internet connection.

Comment: The game does require Internet.  The only reason I realy want to play on the desktop is that I'm curious.